# MySQL Query with variable in Perl

Tags: perl

My Perl is fairly rusty so please forgive.  Trying to write a query using a variable.  Have tried reformatting, just can't seem to get it correctly.  Here is my code, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
my $d_var = "$3\n";
my $query="SELECT id FROM `accounts` WHERE (`accounts`.`named` = ?) LIMIT 1";
my $st_h = $db_h->prepare($query);
$st_h->bind_param(1, '$d_var');
  $st_h->execute;
    my $row = $st_h->fetchrow_array();
```

Comment: When you say you can't get it correctly, do you mean it doesn't parse? Does the query run but not return your results? What happens? (Welcome to SO!) Also, have you tried removing the single-quotes from around `$d_var` in `bind_param()`?

Comment: Yea, I tried $d_var in different notations.  Errors have been changing as I've tried to get it working.  Latest error is:  Can't call method "bind_param" on an undefined value at new.pl line 31, <$log> line 2.

Comment: Under the first line put in a `die "\$d_var not defined" unless defined $d_var;`.

Comment: Added, however d_var is getting a value.  I updated my original post with the current code, new error is:  Use of uninitialized value $row in print at new.pl line 35, <$log> line 14.

Comment: remove the single quote on this line `$st_h->bind_param(1, '$d_var')`

Comment: Did this earlier, same result :(

Comment: I don't really know [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI), but it usually helps to re-read the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/DBI), no matter what module you're using. ( I look at [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util) and [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) quite often. )

Answer (score 1):

Please double check:

1. $3 contains something reasonable
2. concatenating $3's value and "\n" (by interpolation) is correct ("\n" in field?)
3. as ' doesn't interpolate => `my $st_ht->bind_param(1, $d_var);`

(I don't understand the DBI Docs as Chris Ledet does.)

On 2nd thought:

This code snippet:

```
  my $v = "nix nix 1001";
  print "$v\n";
  print '$v\n', "\n";
  if ($v =~ m/(nix) (nix) (\d+)/) {
    print 'found: ', $3, "\n";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM sample01.csv WHERE GRUPPE=?');
    $sth->bind_param(1, $3);
    $sth->execute;
    while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
      print '|', join( '|', @row ), "|\n";
    }
  } else {
    print "no match\n";
  }
```

and the output:

```
DBI: 1.616 DBD::CSV: 0.33
|00000089-6d83-486d-9ddf-30bbbf722583|2011-09-17 16:25:09|1001|
|000004c9-92c6-4764-b320-b1403276321e|2011-11-09 13:52:30|2000|


nix nix 1001
$v\n
found: 1001
|00000089-6d83-486d-9ddf-30bbbf722583|2011-09-17 16:25:09|1001|
```

should illustrate:

1. ' does not interpolate, your '$d_var' will pass this variable name literally to DBI
2. a valid match needs no "\n" to 'work'
3. the param sequence for bind_param is number, value

Comment: You ARE, the MAN.  This is now fixed.  Replacing d_var with $3 in the lookup fixed the issue.  I don't have enough points to give you an upvote, but certainly deserving.

Comment: @user1130364: Thanks for the feedback; I'm glad we solved the problem.

Comment: Funny how four other replies missed the interpolation problem. Upvote for noticing the actual problem rather than merely pointing out stylistic concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're even using `bind_param`. In my opinion, it's far simpler to just pass extra values into `execute`.

```
my $d_var = "$3\n";
my $query = 'SELECT id FROM accounts` WHERE (`accounts`.`named` = ?) LIMIT 1';
my $st_h = $db_h->prepare($query);
$st_h->execute($d_var);
my $row = $st_h->fetchrow_array();
```

Have you considered switching to [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass)?

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean?

```
my $st_ht->bind_param(1, '$d_var');
```

There is no variable being introduced, so why the `my`?

Comment: I've modified the code (what you say makes sense), getting another error now. Error:  Use of uninitialized value $row in print at new.pl line 35, <$log> line 9.

Answer (score 0):

I have $3 printing out prior to execution and there is data contained within the string.

I have d_var="$3\n" as the variable $3 is being generated by a Regex string and doesn't seem to work without \n.

Tried what Chris suggested above, however did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what Dan said (removing the single quote), you binded your param to a possibly none Statement handle object `$st_ht->bind_param(...)` it should be `$st_h->bind_param(...)`.